# Download ZIP file with Jersey

Tags: rest, jersey

I have this method:

```java
@GET
@Path("/download/{cptCodes}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response downloadElectronicComponent(@QueryParam("cptCodes") List<String> codes);
```

I want to create a ZIP file containing a set of files specified by `codes` parameter. First, I have to retrieve those document and then create a ZIP file. This ZIP file can be huge.

I read about `StreamingOutput`, but I saw some post simply returning a file. I guess using `StreamingOutput` is better, but since I don't how is it working, I'm not sure how I should use it.

Comment: Please let me know if my solution worked for you.

Answer (score 4):

The [`StreamingOutput`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/StreamingOutput.html) can be used as following:

```java
@GET
@Path("/download/{cptCodes}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response downloadElectronicComponent(@QueryParam("cptCodes") List<String> codes) {

    StreamingOutput stream = new StreamingOutput() {

        @Override
        public void write(OutputStream os) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
            // Generate your ZIP and write it to the OutputStream
        }
    };

    return Response.ok(stream).build();
}
```

With it, you can stream the output, that is, send data in a series of "chunks".

Comment: Thanks! But should `os` be a `ZipOutputStream` and not some `OutputStream`?

Comment: @Rapster Could you please clarify your comment?

Comment: Well, I'm reading this post https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/zip/create-zip-file-from-multiple-files-with-zipoutputstream/ and I see that `ZipOutputStream` is used. Shouldn't I indicate what kind of `OutputStream` I'm using? Which type of `OutputStream` actually (by default)?

Comment: @Rapster You must copy the ZIP file content to the `OutputStream` `os`. Your `ZipOutputStream` instace must be copied to `os`.

Comment: How is that different to use a `StreamingOutput` rather than a `File` in the response?

Comment: @Rapster This approach allows you to send the file in a series of chunks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116487/discussion-between-rapster-and-cassio-mazzochi-molin).